# Cant get line in line graph to populate in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm trying to build a line graph in D3 but I'm not seeing any of my lines populate. Can someone look over my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong? When I inspect the line path in the console I see some NaN in the d path, I'm assuming this is the source of my problems however perhaps not

Here is my HTML

```
<label class="guideline">
Show Guideline & Curtain
<input type="checkbox" id="show_guideline" />
</label>

<svg></svg>
```

Here is my CSS

```
<style>

body {
font: 10px sans-serif;
margin: 0;
}

path.line {
fill: none;
stroke: #666;
stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

path.area {
fill: #e7e7e7;
}

.axis {
shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis line {
stroke: #fff;
}

.x.axis .minor {
stroke-opacity: .5;
}

.x.axis path {
display: none;
}

.y.axis line, .y.axis path {
fill: none;
stroke: #000;
}

.guideline {
margin-right: 100px;
float: right;
}

</style>
```

Here is my javascript

```
<script>

var margin = {top: 80, right: 80, bottom: 80, left: 80},
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

//var parse = d3.time.format("%b %Y").parse;
var parse = d3.time.format("%Y").parse; 

// Scales and axes.
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]),
y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]),
xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).tickSize(-height).tickSubdivide(true),
yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).ticks(4).orient("right");

// An area generator, for the light fill.
var area = d3.svg.area()
.interpolate("monotone")
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y0(height)
.y1(function(d) { return y(d.incidents); }); 

// A line generator, for the dark stroke.
var line = d3.svg.line()
.interpolate("monotone")
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.incidents); });
```

here is my csv doc

```
d3.csv("static/data/israel/incidents_linechart.csv", type, 
function(error, data) {  

// Filter to one symbol; the S&P 500.
var values = data.filter(function(d) {
return d.country == "Israel";;
});

var unitedStates = data.filter(function(d) {
return d.country == "unitedStates";
});

// Compute the minimum and maximum date, and the maximum price.
x.domain([values[0].date, values[values.length - 1].date]);
y.domain([0, d3.max(values, function(d) { return d.incidents; 
})]).nice();

// Add an SVG element with the desired dimensions and margin.
var svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + 
  ")")

// Add the clip path.
svg.append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "clip")
  .append("rect")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

// Add the x-axis.
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

// Add the y-axis.
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + ",0)")
  .call(yAxis);


var colors = d3.scale.category10();
```

entering my data values here

```
svg.selectAll('.line')
.data([values, unitedStates]) /// can add however many i want here 
.enter()
  .append('path')
    .attr('class', 'line')
    .style('stroke', function(d) {
      return colors(Math.random() * 50);
    })
    .attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip)')
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      return line(d);
    })

/* Add 'curtain' rectangle to hide entire graph */
var curtain = svg.append('rect')
.attr('x', -1 * width)
.attr('y', -1 * height)
.attr('height', height)
.attr('width', width)
.attr('class', 'curtain')
.attr('transform', 'rotate(180)')
.style('fill', '#ffffff')

/* Optionally add a guideline */
var guideline = svg.append('line')
.attr('stroke', '#333')
.attr('stroke-width', 0)
.attr('class', 'guide')
.attr('x1', 1)
.attr('y1', 1)
.attr('x2', 1)
.attr('y2', height)

/* Create a shared transition for anything we're animating */
var t = svg.transition()
.delay(750)
.duration(6000)
.ease('linear')
.each('end', function() {
  d3.select('line.guide')
    .transition()
    .style('opacity', 0)
    .remove()
});

t.select('rect.curtain')
.attr('width', 0);
t.select('line.guide')
.attr('transform', 'translate(' + width + ', 0)')

d3.select("#show_guideline").on("change", function(e) {
guideline.attr('stroke-width', this.checked ? 1 : 0);
curtain.attr("opacity", this.checked ? 0.75 : 1);
})

});

// Parse dates and numbers. We assume values are sorted by date.
function type(d) {
d.date = parse(d.date);
d.incidents = +d.incidents;
return d;
}

</script>
```

Here is some of my data:

[image: data]

any help would be immensely appreciated.

so when I console.log the data in the browser I get the following:

[image]

my incidents column is being repeated twice for every row, once correctly and once incorrectly yielding a NaN

Comment: It does work fine (I've used a sample data). Here: https://jsfiddle.net/a9w3nzh6/ . Can you console log the `data`, `values` array and re-check?

Comment: @Shashank thanks for responding. When I do a console.log I get the following for the first row:  0: {country: "Israel", date: "1970", "incidents ": "1", "": ""}..... perhaps it's not working because of the parenthesis around the numeric & time data values?

Comment: not parenthesis i mean quotations

Comment: That shouldn't be the issue as you're calling the d3.csv's accessor function `type` on every row which would parse the numeric and date values. Can you use the jsfiddle I posted above as a reference and try to locate the issue? 'Cause it works fine for me.

Comment: @Shashank i added a screenshot of what i'm talking about right above. im getting a duplicate "incidents" column, one with the correct data and the other with a NaN. When I type out the data like you did in the fiddle it worked fine, however i'd rather not do it that way as I have a lot of data to add ...

Comment: Got it. Looks like your CSV has an extra space in the "incidents " column which results in the duplication resulting from the `type` function (`d.incidents = +d.incidents`). Take that space out and you'll see the chart render.

Comment: @Shashank thank you!!

Comment: Sure. Glad I could help.